# Convert Parse.com updatedAt

Tags: javascript, datetime, parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how i can convert an date "updatedAt" from parse.com to something I can alter like 2014, sep. 3. I haven't found any explanation to this in the documentation on parse.com.

Here is what i get from the Parse.com:

```
Wed Sep 03 2014 08:29:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

I have tried this:

```
var d = object.updatedAt;
d = new Date(d.iso);
```

When outputting "d" I get "invalid date".

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is updatedAt actually returning an object? Have you tried: d = new Date(object.updatedAt);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d = new Date('Wed Sep 03 2014 08:29:15 GMT+0200 (CEST)');
```

Works just fine.

Try looking at object.updatedAt.iso, to see if your object actually contains the date.

Comment: I had to do convert d.toString() and then i worked :-)